# Цикл наворачивается сам на себя

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер, curl, циклы

Делаю обработчик страниц с вытаскиванием превьюшек, почему-то цикл наворачивается сам на себя

```
require_once 'phpQuery.php';
$author = htmlspecialchars($_POST['author']);
$id_u = array();
$pages = range(1,70);
$fir = 'http://www.site.com/pictures/user/'.$author.'/page/';
foreach($pages as $next){
    $krol = $fir.$next;
    $urka = GetSslPage($krol);
    $krisa = preg_match('/\bclass="next\b/i',$urka);
    unset($urka);
    if($krisa == 1){
        $id_u[] = $krol;
    }else{
        Break(1);
    }
}
$sh = count($id_u);
$sh_next = $sh+1;
$id_u[] = $fir.$sh_next;
echo "У автора галерея из $sh страниц.<br/>";
foreach($id_u as $bac){
    $uro = phpQuery::newDocument(cURLget($bac));
    foreach ($uro->find('a.thumbLink') as $picpage){
    $pq = pq($picpage);
    $href = $pq->attr('href');
```

То он мне показывает что на сайте 1 страница, хотя открываю сам и смотрю - а там 8 страниц.То зацикливается и у меня показывает что всего чуть ли не 8000 страниц.С чем это может быть связано?Регуляркой ищу есть ли на странице элемент списка вида:

```
<li class="next"><a href="/pictures/user/picaythor/page/2">Next &gt;</a></li>
```

Ну и понятное дело если его нету, значит это последняя страница, поэтому делаю Break(1) всего цикла foreach.Где я ошибаюсь и делаю не так?Использую PHP 5.3.

Comment: Если вы решили эту проблему, добавьте, пожалуйста, ответ.